# Integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^5\left(e^{\frac{a}{x}}-1\right)}$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I was integrating the Planck distribution and came across this integral:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac {1}{x^5\cdot \left(e^{\frac{a}{x}}-1\right)} dx$$

From this page: http://w.astro.berkeley.edu/~echiang/rad/ps1ans.pdf 
the given solution is

$$\int_0^\infty \frac {1}{x^5\cdot \left(e^{\frac{1}{x}}-1\right)}dx = \frac {\pi^4}{15} $$

and I could analytically work out that the general solution is

$$\int_0^\infty \frac {1}{x^5\cdot \left(e^{\frac{a}{x}}-1\right)}dx = \frac {\pi^4}{15a^4} $$

I was wondering how one could prove this, and if my general solution is accurate or not.

Comment: Did you not just compute it? Why do you think your computation might be wrong?

Comment: Missing $dx$ in equations.